# Add text to Froala text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, froala

I'm trying to programatically input html into Froala text editor. Based on their documentation this should work:

```
$(function(){
    $('#editor').editable("setHTML", "<p>My custom paragraph.</p>", false);
});
```

But when I reload page I only get empty space, no errors. This is binded to textarea with id `#editor`. If I use this code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#editor').editable({inlineMode : false});
});
```

... then everything is ok.

Does anyone knows how to programatically input html into this editor.

Answer (score 16):

You should try this :

```
$('#editor').froalaEditor('html.set', 'My custom paragraph.');
```

See the detail about `froala` method at this reference:
https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/methods#html.set

Comment: Hello, I have done this.
On edit, the form, when I submit the form then this field didn't post data. what will do to post this field? Thank you

Comment: This worked for me.

Like...
var notification_html = $(this).data('html');
$("textarea#feditor").froalaEditor('html.set', notification_html);

Comment: What was the final approach?

Answer (score 5):

For the users you are looking for v3 answers, You can add text in v3 by:

```
var editor = new FroalaEditor('.selector', {}, function () {
  // Call the method inside the initialized event.
  editor.html.insert('<p>My custom paragraph.</p>');
})
```

Also for if you want to replace the whole content then you can use set method

```
var editor = new FroalaEditor('.selector', {}, function () {
  // Call the method inside the initialized event.
  editor.html.set('<p>My custom paragraph.</p>');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use both. First you have to create the editor, then you can set the HTML

```
$(function(){
    $('#editor').editable({inlineMode : false});
    $('#editor').editable("setHTML", "<p>My custom paragraph.</p>", false);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

With the latest version of Froala this works fine

```
$("#froalaEditor")[0]["data-froala.editor"].html.set('This should work fine');
```

Answer (score 1):

To append a text use `html.insert`

```
$("#editor").froalaEditor('html.insert','<p>new text to append</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

After inserting the HTML use "Sync"

```
$("#editor").editable("insertHTML", "123456", true);
$("#editor").editable("sync");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for note.
in HTML

```
<div id="froala-editor">
  <p>something</p>
</div>
```

and in javascript

```
  $(function() {
    $('div#froala-editor').froalaEditor({
      pastePlain: true
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#editor').froalaEditor('html.set', 'My custom paragraph.');
$('#editor').froalaEditor('undo.saveStep', 'My custom paragraph.');
```

Reference: https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/issues/1578

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it with React js, here is how i did it... FroalaEditorComponent has an event object in it which has initialized as an event. here is the code example:

```
initialized: function () {
               this.html.set(formik?.values?.body); // not working for me
               this.html.set(`<h1>Hello!</h1>`); // working fine
               console.log(this);
            },
```